# How to handle a whole word of a given pattern?

Tags: java, regex

The string : "**A**be **p**eter said **p**an saw his **l**ying **e**xpression", would be validated as correct. But if I entered the the string "Apple" or "APPLE" only, it doesn't validate as correct. What am I missing here?

```
"[Aa].*? p.*? p.*? l.*? e\\S*"
```

Comment: the * will match zero or more instances of . (any character). There is no need to make it optional with a ?

Comment: @kindasimple that's not optional, it makes the `*` to do a non-greedy match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the space and also you need to turn on the case insensitive modifier to do a case insensitive match. So that it would match `Apple` or `APPLE`

```
"(?i)a.*?p.*?p.*?l.*?e\\S*"
```

Code:

```
String s1 = "Abe peter said pan saw his lying expression";
String s2 = "Apple";
String s3 = "APPLE";
System.out.println(s1.matches("(?i)a.*?p.*?p.*?l.*?e\\S*"));
System.out.println(s2.matches("(?i)a.*?p.*?p.*?l.*?e\\S*"));
System.out.println(s3.matches("(?i)a.*?p.*?p.*?l.*?e\\S*"));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
```

Comment: May I ask what `(?i)` means?

Comment: `(?i)` case insensitive modifier. It's makes the letter in your pattern to case insensitive. For ex , if we give the pattern as `"(?i)apple"`, this would match `apple`, `APPle`, `AppLE`, etc case insensitively.

Answer (score 2):

That regex doesn't work on "Apple" because there are space before every symbol after [Aa]. It will work on "A p p l e".